# Removing unmapped OneDrive link in File Explorer

Tags: onedrive, windows-11

After setting up a new computer and connecting to my work Onedrive account, Windows still displays a (broken) link to a non-existent personal OneDrive account:

[image]

How do I remove this broken link without affecting my actual OneDrive folder? The closest solution I've found is [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/onedrive/orphaned-onedrive-link-in-explorer-left-navigation-that-cannot/m-p/56241) but it seems as if that results in breaking more things than fixing them.